# Failure to display result of a php script calculation in the textarea box

Tags: javascript, php, html

I believe that my problem may lie in the way that I am trying to initialize the script. The submit button that I am using seems to just clear the form, and not display any results. I also think there may be a problem with the two lines " $message = $_POST['textarea'];" and "echo $result + $message;" I am not sure if that is the correct way to produce a result into a text area box, as well as display the miles driven and total cost in their separate text boxes. I want this one button to do all three tasks. Is there a way to do this efficiently with PHP?

Edit: Corrected version of the code. Thank you @Fred-ii-!

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $x = $_POST['beginningOdometerReading'];
    $y = $_POST['endingOdometerReading'];
    $z = $_POST['daysRentedCar'];
    $miles = $y - $x; 
    $result = (15 * $z) + ($miles * 0.12);
    $message = $_POST['textarea'];
  echo $result + $message; } 
?>
<html>
<head>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<hr><br>
<form action="index4.php" method="post" name id="Main">
<input type="text" id="name" name="customerName" placeholder="Enter your name here" size="30px">   
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="address" name="customerAddress" placeholder="Enter your street address here" size="50px">   
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="city" name="customerCity" placeholder="What city do you live in?" size="30px">   
<br><br>
<input type="number" id="zip" name="customerZip" placeholder="Enter your zip code" size="30px">   
<br><br>
<input type="number" id="bOdometer" name="beginningOdometerReading" placeholder="Start odometer reading" size="80px">   
<br><br>
<input type="number" id="eOdometer" name="endingOdometerReading" placeholder="End odometer reading" width="80px"> 
<br><br>
<input type="number" id="daysRented" name="daysRentedCar" placeholder="Days rented" size="50px">  
<br><br>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
<br><br>
Miles Driven: <input type="number" id='miles' min="1" max"10000" readonly="" />
Total Cost: <input type="number" id='result' min="1" max"10000" readonly="" />
<br><br>
Summary: <textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="thetextarea" id="textarea">     </textarea>
<br><br>
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>       
<hr>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you've seen my answer, but I've made a few edits since my original posting and there were many syntax errors. You will need to reload it if you have seen it. You will also need to go over your PHP to match up any POST arrays/variables that you may not have included. All POST arrays must match the related inputs.

Comment: @Fred-ii- All of your edits have been applied. The grand total is now being displayed at the top of the page. Now for the "Miles Driven: <input type="number" id='miles' min="1" max="10000" readonly="" />
AND Total Cost: <input type="number" id='result' min="1" max="10000" readonly="" />" How would I get the result of bOdometer - eOdometer into the "miles" box and the grand total into the "result" box?

Comment: If you want to echo inside a textarea, just do something like `<textarea><?php echo $variable; ?></textarea>` but you will need to use a conditional statement for it, or a ternary operator. Otherwise, it will throw an undefined variable notice.

Comment: You also overwrote your original question with my code and not marking it as an edit. I performed a rollback to the original question. People would have seen your new code and compare it with mine and think/say: *"your code is the same as the OP's, so why the answer?"* and I'd get downvoted for it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Somewhat new to Stackoverflow, my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here.

One of the problems being with your conditional statement:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

it is looking for a named element called "submit" which your submit button is not named.

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

name it:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

and you might have been relying on "id" for it. In this instance, you can't.

That is why you're getting back a blank page.

Having used an `else{ echo "Error"; }` would have echo'd "Error".

For example:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $x = $_POST['beginningOdometerReading'];
    $y = $_POST['endingOdometerReading'];
    $z = $_POST['daysRentedCar'];
    $miles = $y - $x; 
    $result = (15 * $z) + ($miles * 0.12);
    $message = $_POST['textarea'];
  echo $result + $message; } 

  else { echo "Error"; }
?>
```

Then you have

```
$message = $_POST['textarea'];
```

but your textarea is named `name="thetextarea"`.

- Both of those need to match in names.

You are also using the wrong concatenate operator `+` for

```
echo $result + $message;
```

that needs to be a dot. The `+` sign is a JS/C++ method of concatenation, if one of those variables contains a string.

```
echo $result . $message;
```

or

```
echo $result . " ". $message;
```

Had it been a mathematical equation from two variables, then yes; that would have been a valid operator, just not in this case, since you are trying to echo from the `$message` variable, which is for the "textarea", being "text" and not an integer.

Sidenote: To ensure that you are indeed passing an integer to a POST array, add `(int)` to it. Example: `$x = (int)$_POST['beginningOdometerReading'];`

**Edit:** I found a few more errors in your form.

You have 2x instances of `max"10000"` it's missing an equal sign `max="10000"`

and you might be missing name attributes for both of these (which I already outlined are missing `=` signs for `max"10000"`.

```
Miles Driven: <input type="number" id='miles' min="1" max"10000" readonly="" />
Total Cost: <input type="number" id='result' min="1" max"10000" readonly="" />
```

- If you're relying on JS as you tagged this as, please edit your question and add that code. However, there was no code in your PHP to support this.
- You've a syntax error in `<form>` being `name id="Main"`
- You will need to adjust your actual code accordingly.

Rewrite:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $x = $_POST['beginningOdometerReading'];
    $y = $_POST['endingOdometerReading'];
    $z = $_POST['daysRentedCar'];
    $miles = $y - $x; 
    $result = (15 * $z) + ($miles * 0.12);
    $message = $_POST['thetextarea'];
  echo $result . " " . $message; } 

  else { echo "Error"; }
?>
```

---

Error reporting would have signaled an undefined index notice for both of those.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: How do I do the equivalent of area.value='Name: '+customerName+'\nAddress: '+customerAdd+'\nTotal Cost: $'+totalCost+'';} in PHP?

Comment: @user9018 I believe I answered the original question http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30836549/1 but then you added to the question after. If you want to show multiple variables, concatenate them with a dot, just as I showed in my answer, and for example `echo $result . " " . $message;` that's how it's done as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to give name for input type `submit` button like

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

And try to remove from **`action=''`** because when you submit it directly takes to the `index4.php` and

> error in form statement also you does not provide `name` you leave it empty like `name id="Main"`

```
<form action="index4.php" method="post" name="Main" id="Main">
```

> And use echo statement like

```
echo $result,$message; }
```